# SectionIndexTitlesForTableView Display Options

Tags: uitableview, ios5, indexing

All,

I added a section index (A-Z 1-9) to my table view and I am getting the following displayed:

[image]

I am assuming the dots are there in order to fit the index  in the view???  How can I fix? Probably nothing can be done if in fact I would like all indices to be visible but I am curious how others have solved this issue...

```
 (gdb) po indices
 <__NSArrayM 0x196410>
 (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to implement your own. Why do you have 1-9? The standard is just using a # sign to jump to that section.